# Partial view is not rendering properly

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two drop-downs when we are selecting the first one we need to update the second one.
Below is my view:

```
@model HostingManager.Models.ContractManager
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CustomCreate"; 
}
@Html.Partial("_GroupDDL" , Model)
@Html.Partial("SelectClient", Model)
@Html.Partial("SelectContract", Model)
```

Below is first Drop-down (Partial View: `_GroupDDL`)

```
@model HostingManager.Models.ContractManager

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectClient", "Contracts", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "IClients" }))
{ 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        m => m.SelectedGroupId,
        new SelectList(Model.IGroups, "id", "name"),
        string.Empty
    )
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SelectedGroupId').change(function () {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Below is Second Drop-down (Partial View: `SelectClient`)

```
@model HostingManager.Models.ContractManager

@if (Model.IClients != null && Model.IClients.Count() > 0)
{
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectContracts", "Contracts", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "IContracts" }))
    { 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedGroupId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.SelectedClientId,
            new SelectList(Model.IClients, "id", "cname"),
            string.Empty
        )
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SelectedClientId').change(function () {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Below is my Controller action:

```
public ActionResult CustomCreate()
{
    ContractManager CM = new ContractManager();
    CM.IGroups = db.groups.ToList();
    return View(CM);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectClient(int? SelectedGroupId)
{
    ContractManager CM = new ContractManager();
    CM.IClients = new List();
    if (SelectedGroupId.HasValue)
    {
        CM.IClients = db.client.ToList();
    }
    return PartialView("SelectClient", CM);
}
```

**Now The problem:**

In Debugging Mode when I'm selecting the first DDL. Control is coming to second DDL with the values but the Second DDL is not appearing on the View. i.e. We can't see the Second DDL on the UI.

I have already added ajax script in my Layout and also enabled in `web.config`.
I'll filter the Second DDL the once if I can overcome this.

Comment: Why are you using partial views and ajax form submissions just for one DDL?

Answer (score 0):

Besides of perfection the example, you can do something like this in _GroupDDL partial view with [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SelectedGroupId').change(function () {
        $.post('@Url.Action("SelectClient", "Contracts")', {SelectedGroupId: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
           $('#SelectedClientId').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It will call the SelectClient action of Controller each time you change the SelectedGroupId ddl, it will return the html of SelectedClientId with all options based on parent/master ddl selection.

Comment: Hi ararog, Thanks for quick response but it not working. I Just checked as you suggested but it is not calling SelectClient of Controller. As per My Posted Code It is calling the SelectClient of Controller but my Main View is not updating with the updated partial view.

Comment: The reason to not be calling is the second argument of Url.Action, I passed "Controller" the correct is "Contracts", the answer has been updated.

Comment: Yes I corrected it while checking but it is not working out :(

Comment: In My posted code everything is working well but the Second Drop down box  is not displaying while excution completes..